# Newbie : ActiveMQ with Camel

Tags: xml, spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm pretty new to this topic and need some explanation...

We have a running ActiveMQ-Server, which should now be enhanced with Apache Camel routing and processing. Our whole configuration is XML based.

My first approach was to do a plain `<import resource="camel.xml">` at the end of our activemq.xml, but this seems to be the wrong path.

These are the current transortConnectors:

```
<transportConnectors>
    <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://localdev:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://localdev:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://localdev:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://localdev:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://localdev:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="mqtt+ws" uri="ws://localdev:1884?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="vm" uri="vm://localdev" />
</transportConnectors>
```

And this is our camel.xml:

```
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <camelContext id="camel" depends-on="broker-localdev" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="devRawMap">
            <description>Redirect for test message</description>
            <from uri="activemq:topic:alpha.topic.DEV.INTERNAL.*.RAW"/>
            <to uri="activemq:queue:alpha.queue.DEV"/>
        </route>
        <route id="liveMap">
            <description>Redirect for Live data</description>
            <from uri="activemq:topic:devRoot.topic.LIVE.*.RAW"/>
            <to uri="activemq:queue:devRoot.queue.LIVE"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>

    <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" >
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
                <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localdev?create=false"/>
                <property name="userName" value="user"/>
                <property name="password" value="pass"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Whatever configuration I make, the messages are not routed from topic to queue and I get the log messages:

```
Broker localhost not started so using localdev instead
Connector vm://localhost started
```

Am I following the wrong approach to this?

Any help is highly appreciated

[EDIT 01]

Is the problem maybe in having alot of persisted topics beingh loaded from kahadb alogn with using the RuntimeConfigurationPlugin?
It takes a while until all topics are loaded and created, especial with having log4j set to debug.
Furthermore the RuntimeConfigurationPlugin requires the broker to set "start=false" during init. see [here](http://activemq.apache.org/runtime-configuration.html)

Comment: Can you try `<import resource="classpath*:camel.xml" />`? Also, try and enable full debug logging to see if you can extract more 
information.

Comment: which version of camel are you using. When you start the application are queues getting created on your activemq?

Comment: Hi all queues and topics are created. I can sent to them from external nodejs scripts and also read queues via stomp connection. But the very moment I start Camel, I see in the logs vm://localhost is being created.

Comment: using classpath*: didn't help

Answer (score 0):

your import `<import resource="camel.xml"/>` must be between broker and beans elements like this if the `camel.xml` is in the same folder than `activemq.xml` :

```
    </broker> 
    <import resource="camel.xml"/> 
</beans>
```

try by removing `<import resource="camel.xml"/>` and adding directly the content of `camel.xml` to the `activemq.xml` by removing `<beans>` element :

```
    </broker> 
    <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"  depends-on="broker-localdev" >
        <route id="devRawMap">
            <description>Redirect for test message</description>
            <from uri="activemq:topic:alpha.topic.DEV.INTERNAL.*.RAW"/>
            <to uri="activemq:queue:alpha.queue.DEV"/>
        </route>
        <route id="liveMap">
            <description>Redirect for Live data</description>
            <from uri="activemq:topic:devRoot.topic.LIVE.*.RAW"/>
            <to uri="activemq:queue:devRoot.queue.LIVE"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>

    <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" >
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
                <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
                <property name="userName" value="user"/>
                <property name="password" value="pass"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: I did as you said, now it throws an exception: Line 1 in XML document from class path resource [camel.xml] is invalid; Cannot find the declaration of element 'camelContext'. But my schema location includes `http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd`

Comment: i have updated my answer, if you want to verify if all destinations are created by Camel you need to verify this after AMQ start and before any other client connection because any producer or consumer can create them

Comment: Maybe this is a hint, before I try your edit: The very moment I sent a message to the watched queue the log states Publishing: vm://localhost for broker transport URI: vm://localhost | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ VMTransport: vm://localhost#5`

Comment: Before starting any external client you can check the web console to see if there is any connection to your topics...

Comment: This is what is puzzling me - there is no subscription. Actually I would expect Camel to make a subscription for the route. What I just saw is, that there is a new directory created called 'activemq-data' in the home directory of my instance... Which makes the whole localhost behaviour even more strange...

Comment: localdev is the name of the host ?? Try vm://localhost?

Comment: activemq-data is the kahadb persistence directory

Comment: Connect with visualVM to AMQ to check camel context and destinations clients

Comment: the thing is the instance has already a data dir. this activemq-data dir is only created when I use the camel context. This is really weird

Comment: Still the same: `Connector vm://localhost started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector` - this is driving me nuts!