# ActiveMQ with Camel basics

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, amq

I already googled for a while looking for step by step tutorials explaining setup and integration of ActiveMQ with Camel, but had little success to find a basic tutorial.
I already have a running and configured ActiveMQ server but I just can't get the Camel Component up and running. It always creates a separate broker and I just can't make Camel connect to the existing broker instance.

Any hints where I can find basic tutorials on how to integrate Camel and develop a better understanding on how those two work together?
Please do not refere to Camel-Website, as this along with the docs for ActiveMQ where my primary source to fight through the stuff, but it helped only a little on setup, configuration and through understanding of both packages.

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: do you use spring or spring-boot?

Comment: @MickaëlB: Sorry, my intention is to find a tutorial, which explains the basics preferrably online.

Comment: I have tried get an AMQ-Camel setup running. But I just can't make it work. I suppose my understanding for the Camel-AMQ / AMQ-Camel corelation is to shallow... I have an [open question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046760/newbie-activemq-with-camel) here. The answers and hints there made me post this question as there is obvious lack of understanding the basics. The Apache site and examples are not explaining the topics enough and Google searches didn't yield any results helping out on this...

Comment: @pvpkiran: I'm using Spring XML DSL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is configuration of Active MQ with camel.

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
          class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pooledConnectionFactory"
          class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <property name="maxConnections" value="8"/>
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsConfig"
          class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="activemq"
          class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig"/>
    </bean>
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

<route id="*****">
            <from uri="+++++++++" />
            <choice>
                    <to uri="activemq:queue:**********"/>
                            </choice>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

Comment: Can you explain in brief why there is a choice tag inside the route configuration?

Comment: It was part of my code. There were some requirement to send file depending on conditions . That's why I used choice element with simple tag. If you want to set some condition before routing file to specific location, you can use <choice> element with <when> tag. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can consider some of the Camel books which has extensive information about all sorts of stuff with Camel, also how to use it with JMS and AMQ. 
http://camel.apache.org/books

And there is some examples from AMQ you can look at as well: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples

And you can try to find some 3rd party blogs or articles that cover AMQ with Camel: http://camel.apache.org/articles

And recently there was this article about AMQ with Camel:
http://www.puretechy.com/blog/apache-camel-activemq-example